# Confusion about pullback in $\sf{Set}$.

Tags: category-theory

Given sets $A, B, C$ and set functions $f: A \to C$ and $g: B \to C$, everywhere I look seems to be telling me that the pullback is $A \times_C B = \left\{(a, b) \mid f(a) = f(b)\right\}$ (together with the usual projective maps).  I do not understand why we are *not* required in the construction to quotient this set by the relation $(a, b) \sim (a', b')$ if and only if $f(a) = f(a')$ (equivalently, if and only if $g(b) = g'(b)$).  Why do I say this?  Because if we want $A \times_C B$ to be a pullback, then we want it to admit a *unique* set function from any other set $Z$ to $A \times_C B$ (of course, we assume $Z$ comes together with $f' : Z \to A$ and $g' : Z \to B$ such that the diagram commutes).  One can easily imagine that for a given $x \in Z$ and setting $c_x \equiv f(f'(x)) = g(g'(x)$ that $A_{c_x} \equiv f^{-1}(c_x)$ or $B_{c_x} \equiv g^{-1}(c_x)$ may have more than one element.  Then in general, one can define many possible functions from $Z \to A \times_C B$ by sending $x$ to any element of $A_{c_x} \times B_{c_x}$ and the diagram will commute, thus violating the desired property that such a map is unique.  Indeed, as far as I can see, the only way to avoid this is to quotient out by the relation presented above.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that in general, one can send $x \in Z$ to many different elements in $A \times_C B$. How is that true? Remember that the diagrams involving $Z$, $A \times_C B$ and $A$, as well as $Z$, $A \times_C B$ and $B$ are required to commute. Thus the only option is to send $x$ to $(f'(x),g'(x))$.

Comment: I had considered that, but I did not think that that condition was a requirement.  Are you saying that when one says "the diagram commutes", in general this means that not just the "outer diagram" but also the "inner diagrams" commute as well?   I did not know this as a part of the definition, and it is certainly important to know if it is true!

Comment: So that, say, if Alice and Bob start at the beginning with the same object and they both walk paths to the end of the diagram, then whenever they meet each other, it is required that they posses the same object at that moment (in contrast, my understanding of ``commutative diagram'' when I wrote this question was that they are only required to the posses the same object when they meet at the finish line).